# Оператор выбора в Java. If в Java

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Я еще совсем зелен в java, при вводе male, все равно выводится Ms(Miss/Missis) + ник, хотя должно выводиться Mr.

```
package com.company.Start;

import com.company.objects.Visitor;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner n = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("What's your name?");
    String name = n.nextLine();

    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("What's your sex(male/female)? ");
    String sex = s.next();

    Random rnd = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
    int cash = rnd.nextInt(3000);

    Visitor join = new Visitor(name, sex);

    String mrs;

    if (sex == "male")
        mrs = "Mr ";
    else
        mrs = "Ms ";

   System.out.println("Hello, Dear " + mrs + name);
}
```

Comment: Строки нужно сравнивать через метод `equals`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для сравнения строк используйте метод `equals`. Если использовать `==`, то выражение вернет `true` только при `stringVar == stringVar`. Короче сравнение у строк работает по другому.

И еще, правильнее было бы написать:

```
if (sex.equals("male"))
    mrs = "Mr ";
else if (sex.equals("female"))
    mrs = "Ms ";
else
    mrs = "UnknownSex"
```